# Mangled member function name different during dllimport

Tags: dllimport, mismatch

I'm getting some unresolved externals when importing a DLL of a project (Project 1) in a .exe project (Project 2) using MSVC 2013 (it compiles fine in Mingw 4.8.1):

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class chakra::Message * __thiscall chakra::PublisherSubscriberChannel::GetMessageA(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_?GetMessageA@PublisherSubscriberChannel@chakra@@QAEPAVMessage@2@_K@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Bar2::ProcessMessages(void)" (?ProcessMessages@Bar2@@UAEXXZ)
test_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class chakra::Message * __thiscall chakra::PublisherSubscriberChannel::GetMessageA(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_?GetMessageA@PublisherSubscriberChannel@chakra@@QAEPAVMessage@2@_K@Z)
```

The function GetMessage is a member function of class PublisherSubscriberChannel of namespace chakra in Project 1.

Examined the .exp and .dll file of Project 1 using dumpbin.exe /exports and found the function to be exported as **?GetMessage@PublisherSubscriberChannel@chakra@@QAEPAVMessage@2@_K@Z** whereas during importing it is looking for **?GetMessageA@PublisherSubscriberChannel@chakra@@QAEPAVMessage@2@_K@Z** as per the above error.

It happens only when I #include "Ogre.h" or any of the other Ogre headers in test_wrap.cxx file (which is a SWIG generated file).

Does anyone have any idea why the function name mismatch with the extra **'A'**?

Comment: GetMessage() was an unlucky name, it matches the name of a winapi function.  Which is converted to GetMessageA or GetMessageW by a macro.  You could put `#undef GetMessageA` after your #include for the windows headers to avoid this.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for pointing out the source of error! `#undef GetMessage` worked though, not `#undef GetMessageA`. On searching further with this info, there is no elegant way to avoid this except renaming my function or the way you suggested, is there?

Comment: That's correct.  Elegance is off the table whenever you need to fight the preprocessor.  If this DLL is going to be used by others then renaming the function is the best way.